# Bing maps v7 to v8 upgrade causes increase in billed requests

Tags: bing-maps

I recently completed upgrading bing maps from v7 to v8 for our dealerlocator. Since then we have observed increase in the no. of billed requests.

I did not change the way map API were being called during the upgrade process. Still, it shows an increase in no. of billed requests.

Can someone help me understand any specific reason for the same? Also how do I calculate no. of billed requests using JS in my code during development? Ideally I want to count the no. of requests for every load of this particular module. Please help :(

Comment: Do you not have/use a separate dev/test key for development?

Comment: Yes, we do that. But I do not know how to get a granular report of usage. Also, how do we know which requests are actually billed while using dev key?

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply loading a map a single billable transaction will be generated each time the map is loaded. If you load the map on page load then the number of page views would normally be around the same number as billable transactions. If you use the search or direction modules they will generate non-billable transactions as they are part of the map session.

If you use the auto suggest module, without a map, this will generate a billable transaction the first time a suggestion is selected.

We have done a lot of testing and have most V7 apps migrated to V8. We haven't seen any increases in usage in transactions in general. Any increases that were observed were due to the following:

- App developers were comparing current month to previous month. This isn't accurate as web traffic generally fluctuates month to month. It is best to look at the last two years worth of reports to see if the month is question is typically a higher month and to also look at the average month on month growth as web traffic usually increases over time.
- The new application attracted more users to use it. Sometimes additional marketing may have also been involved.
- There was an issue with the code that the developer migrated which generated more transactions. For example, calling the map load function twice, once using the page onload like in V7 and once using the callback parameter in V8. This would result in twice as many map transactions being generated, but appear as only a single map on the page.
- The previous application didn't use a key and either used v6 of Bing Maps or had CSS which hide the error message that appears in V7. We have seen this in a number of applications. Basically, the old application should have been generating more transactions than it was.

A list of the different ways transactions are generated is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff859477.aspx